Forecasting ARIMA(0,0,1) model by hand - trouble with MA elements
I am having issues forecasting a stationary ARIMA(0,0,1) time-series. I currently have 500 observations of the process, and want to predict the coming three periods.
Using Stata software, I am able to create static and dynamic predictions easily enough, using the following two lines of code:
predict yiv_static, xb //STATIC PREDICTION
predict yiv_dynamic, xb dynamic(501) //DYNAMIC PREDICTION

The issue occurs when I attempt to verify these predictions 'by hand'. My current process is:
Regarding the ARIMA(0,0,1) model, I'm using method to estimate:
y_t = c' - Theta * ε_t-1

With c' being the adjusted constant; c' = c * (1 + Theta)
Theta being 0.8289
ε_t being calculated as εt=yt+θ*ε_t−1 (equal to 1.060531 in the first period)
Does anyone have experience in this? Should it be of interest, my current Stata code looks as follows:
arima yiii if t<=500, arima(0,0,1)
scalar cons_iii = _b[_cons]
scalar cons_adj_iii = cons_iii * (1 + Theta1_iii)
scalar Theta1_iii = [ARMA]_b[L1.ma]

gen yiii_error = yiii if _n == 1
replace yiii_error = yiii + Theta1_iii * L1.yiii_error if _n > 1

gen yiii_static_veri = cons_adj_iii + Theta1_iii * L1.yiii_error // STATIC FORECAST BY HAND

